# Ui-Grid is not working on Azure . i have created Ui-Grid that is working on local but not on Azure after hosting

Tags: html, angularjs, azure, bootstrap-4

I have created a web page where I am using UI-Gird of angularjs and bind data from API. The UI-grid is working fine while running locally but not working while hosting on Azure.

```html
<div class="mainContent" ng-app="gdapp" ng-controller="dashBoardController"> 
    <div class="divGrid"> 
        <div class="ui-grid-collapsible" ui-grid-auto-resize ui-grid="gridOptions">
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by Not working? Do you face any error?. Also, Please post your code.

Comment: there is no error in console code is here '<div class="mainContent" ng-app="gdapp" ng-controller="dashBoardController"> <div class="divGrid">
         <div  class="ui-grid-collapsible"  ui-grid-auto-resize ui-grid="gridOptions"></div>
       </div>
</div> '

Comment: Could you elaborate how did you host your app into Azure?

Comment: i have created a web app and on deploy the code via oneDrive . other than ui-Grid everything is working fine. like i am using http.get and http.post and toaster